# How to mock objects from other classes created during InjectMocks?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, junit, mockito

I want to test my saveEmployee method but the problem is during @InjectMocks, constructor of EmployeeBase class is called and fetchEmployees() method is called. This method aim is to fetch data from database to employees List in the EmployeeBase class. The problem is this method use fields from Constants class and I am getting following result when I run the program. How to mock it properly?

```
class EmployeeBaseTest {
    @InjectMocks
    private EmployeeBase employeeBase;

    @Mock
    private Response response;
    
    @BeforeEach
    void beforeEach() {
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    void saveEmployeeTest() {
        // given
        Employee employee = new Employee();

        // when
        when(fetchEmployees()).thenReturn(Collections.emptyList());
        employeeBase.saveEmployee(employee);
        
        
        // then
        assertEquals("TEST", response.getBody());
    }
}
```

```
public class EmployeeBase {
    private final Response response;
    private final List<Employee> employees;

    public EmployeeBase(Response response) {
        this.response = response;
        employees = fetchEmployees();
    }

    public void saveEmployee(Employee employee) {
        //...
    }
}
```

```
public final class EmployeeUtils {

    private EmployeeUtils() {}

    public static List<Employee> fetchEmployees() {
        ScanRequest scanRequest = new ScanRequest().withTableName(EMPLOYEES);
        ScanResult scanResult = AMAZON_DYNAMO_DB.scan(scanRequest);
        List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Map<String, AttributeValue> employee : scanResult.getItems()){
            employees.add(parseEmployee(employee));
        }
        return employees;
    }
}
```

```
public final class Constants {
    protected static final String EMPLOYEES = "EMPLOYEES";
    protected static final AmazonDynamoDB AMAZON_DYNAMO_DB = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.defaultClient();

    private Constants() {}
}
```

**AFTER UPDATES**

Still not working. Error I am getting:

```
C:\Users\michal\.jdks\corretto-11.0.10\bin\java.exe -ea -Didea.test.cyclic.buffer.size=1048576 "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=55542:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3.2\lib\idea_rt.jar;C:\Users\michal\.m2\repository\org\junit\platform\junit-platform-launcher\1.4.1\junit-platform-launcher-1.4.1.jar;C:\Users\michal\.m2\repository\org\junit\platform\junit-platform-engine\1.4.1\junit-platform-engine-1.4.1.jar;C:\Users\michal\.m2\repository\org\junit\vintage\junit-vintage-engine\5.3.2\junit-vintage-engine-5.3.2.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3.2\plugins\junit\lib\junit5-rt.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3.2\plugins\junit\lib\junit-rt.jar;C:\Users\michal\Documents\idea-projects\serverless\post-employee\target\test-classes;C:\Users\michal\Documents\idea-projects\serverless\post-employee\target\classes;C:\Users\michal\.m2\repository\com\amazonaws\aws-lambda-java-core\1.2.1\aws-lambda-java-core-1.2.1.jar;C:\Users\michal\.m2\repository\com\amazonaws\aws-lambda-java-events\3.6.0\aws-lambda-java-events-3.6.0.jar;C:\Users\michal\.m2\repository\joda-time\joda-time\2.6\joda-time-2.6.jar;C:\Users\michal\.m2\repository\com\amazonaws\aws-java-sdk-dynamodb\1.11.957\aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.957.jar;C:\Users\michal\.m2\repository\com\amazonaws\aws-java-sdk-s3\1.11.957\aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.957.jar;C:\Users\michal\.m2\repository\com\amazonaws\aws-java-sdk-kms\1.11.957\aws-java-sdk-kms-1.11.957.jar;C:\Users\michal\.m2\repository\com\amazonaws\aws-java-sdk-core\1.11.957\aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.957.jar;C:\Users\michal\.m2\repository\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1.3\commons-logging-1.1.3.jar;C:\Users\michal\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpclient\4.5.13\httpclient-4.5.13.jar;C:\Users\michal\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.4.13\httpcore-4.4.13.jar;C:\Users\michal\.m2\repository\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.11\commons-codec-1.11.jar;C:\Users\michal\.m2\repository\software\amazon\ion\ion-java\1.0.2\ion-java-1.0.2.jar;C:\Users\michal\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.6.7.4\jackson-databind-2.6.7.4.jar;C:\Users\michal\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.6.0\jackson-annotations-2.6.0.jar;C:\Users\michal\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.6.7\jackson-core-2.6.7.jar;C:\Users\michal\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\dataformat\jackson-dataformat-cbor\2.6.7\jackson-dataformat-cbor-2.6.7.jar;C:\Users\michal\.m2\repository\com\amazonaws\jmespath-java\1.11.957\jmespath-java-1.11.957.jar;C:\Users\michal\.m2\repository\org\projectlombok\lombok\1.18.18\lombok-1.18.18.jar;C:\Users\michal\.m2\repository\com\googlecode\json-simple\json-simple\1.1.1\json-simple-1.1.1.jar;C:\Users\michal\.m2\repository\junit\junit\4.10\junit-4.10.jar;C:\Users\michal\.m2\repository\org\hamcrest\hamcrest-core\1.1\hamcrest-core-1.1.jar;C:\Users\michal\.m2\repository\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.8.6\gson-2.8.6.jar;C:\Users\michal\.m2\repository\org\junit\jupiter\junit-jupiter-engine\5.3.2\junit-jupiter-engine-5.3.2.jar;C:\Users\michal\.m2\repository\org\apiguardian\apiguardian-api\1.0.0\apiguardian-api-1.0.0.jar;C:\Users\michal\.m2\repository\org\junit\platform\junit-platform-engine\1.3.2\junit-platform-engine-1.3.2.jar;C:\Users\michal\.m2\repository\org\opentest4j\opentest4j\1.1.1\opentest4j-1.1.1.jar;C:\Users\michal\.m2\repository\org\junit\jupiter\junit-jupiter-api\5.3.2\junit-jupiter-api-5.3.2.jar;C:\Users\michal\.m2\repository\org\mockito\mockito-inline\3.6.28\mockito-inline-3.6.28.jar;C:\Users\michal\.m2\repository\org\mockito\mockito-core\3.6.28\mockito-core-3.6.28.jar;C:\Users\michal\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.10.18\byte-buddy-1.10.18.jar;C:\Users\michal\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy-agent\1.10.18\byte-buddy-agent-1.10.18.jar;C:\Users\michal\.m2\repository\org\objenesis\objenesis\3.1\objenesis-3.1.jar;C:\Users\michal\.m2\repository\org\junit\platform\junit-platform-commons\1.4.1\junit-platform-commons-1.4.1.jar" com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5 -junit5 EmployeeBaseTest,saveEmployeeTest
Apr 06, 2021 5:38:37 PM com.amazonaws.util.EC2MetadataUtils getItems
WARNING: Unable to retrieve the requested metadata (/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document). Failed to connect to service endpoint: 
com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Failed to connect to service endpoint: 
    at com.amazonaws.internal.EC2ResourceFetcher.doReadResource(EC2ResourceFetcher.java:100)
    at com.amazonaws.internal.EC2ResourceFetcher.doReadResource(EC2ResourceFetcher.java:70)
    at com.amazonaws.internal.InstanceMetadataServiceResourceFetcher.readResource(InstanceMetadataServiceResourceFetcher.java:75)
    at com.amazonaws.internal.EC2ResourceFetcher.readResource(EC2ResourceFetcher.java:66)
    at com.amazonaws.util.EC2MetadataUtils.getItems(EC2MetadataUtils.java:403)
    at com.amazonaws.util.EC2MetadataUtils.getData(EC2MetadataUtils.java:372)
    at com.amazonaws.util.EC2MetadataUtils.getData(EC2MetadataUtils.java:368)
    at com.amazonaws.util.EC2MetadataUtils.getEC2InstanceRegion(EC2MetadataUtils.java:283)
    at com.amazonaws.regions.InstanceMetadataRegionProvider.tryDetectRegion(InstanceMetadataRegionProvider.java:59)
    at com.amazonaws.regions.InstanceMetadataRegionProvider.getRegion(InstanceMetadataRegionProvider.java:50)
    at com.amazonaws.regions.AwsRegionProviderChain.getRegion(AwsRegionProviderChain.java:46)
    at com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsClientBuilder.determineRegionFromRegionProvider(AwsClientBuilder.java:475)
    at com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsClientBuilder.setRegion(AwsClientBuilder.java:458)
    at com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsClientBuilder.configureMutableProperties(AwsClientBuilder.java:424)
    at com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsSyncClientBuilder.build(AwsSyncClientBuilder.java:46)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.defaultClient(AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.java:53)
    at com.mw.workplanningservice.util.Constants.<clinit>(Constants.java:15)
    at com.mw.workplanningservice.service.EmployeeBase.saveEmployee(EmployeeBase.java:28)
    at EmployeeBaseTest.saveEmployeeTest(EmployeeBaseTest.java:34)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:628)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:171)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:167)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:114)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:59)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:229)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:197)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:191)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:220)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:53)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:107)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
    at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:177)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:474)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:569)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:242)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:341)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:362)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1253)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1232)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1081)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:1015)
    at com.amazonaws.internal.ConnectionUtils.connectToEndpoint(ConnectionUtils.java:52)
    at com.amazonaws.internal.EC2ResourceFetcher.doReadResource(EC2ResourceFetcher.java:80)
    ... 69 more


java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.mw.workplanningservice.service.EmployeeBase.saveEmployee(EmployeeBase.java:28)
    at EmployeeBaseTest.saveEmployeeTest(EmployeeBaseTest.java:34)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:628)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:171)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:167)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:114)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:59)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:229)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:197)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:191)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:220)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:53)
Caused by: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to find a region via the region provider chain. Must provide an explicit region in the builder or setup environment to supply a region.
    at com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsClientBuilder.setRegion(AwsClientBuilder.java:462)
    at com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsClientBuilder.configureMutableProperties(AwsClientBuilder.java:424)
    at com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsSyncClientBuilder.build(AwsSyncClientBuilder.java:46)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.defaultClient(AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.java:53)
    at com.mw.workplanningservice.util.Constants.<clinit>(Constants.java:15)
    ... 53 more


Process finished with exit code -1
```

Code:

```
class EmployeeBaseTest {

    @Test
    void saveEmployeeTest() {
        try (MockedStatic<EmployeeUtils> mockedScope = Mockito.mockStatic(EmployeeUtils.class)) {
            mockedScope.when(EmployeeUtils::fetchEmployees).thenReturn(Collections.emptyList());
            var response = Mockito.mock(Response.class);
            var employeeBase = new EmployeeBase(response);
            employeeBase.saveEmployee(new Employee());
            assertEquals("TEST", response.getBody());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What Mockito and JUnit versions do you use?

Comment: Look at the stack trace: now the error is thrown not from `EmployeeBase` constructor, but from `EmployeeBase. saveEmployee()`! I assume you use `AMAZON_DYNAMO_DB` field in this method. As this is method under test, what you really want is a mock of AMAZON_DYNAMO_DB. As said in an answer - having it as a static field makes it problematic - you would need to mock static `AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.defaultClient()`. If EmployeeBase is some kind of db interface, I suggest passing AMAZON_DYNAMO_DB as a field to a constructor of EmployyBase - that will make your testing a lot easier.

Comment: I use AMAZON_DYNAMO_DB in fetchEmployees method in EmployeeUtils class and yes - this is a static field. What should I do to make tests work and not chaning structure of the code? I want AMAZON_DYNAMO_DB field to stay static in Constants class. Can you show me how to write test properly using static mocking?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Mockito#mockStatic` for this.

```java
try (MockedStatic<EmployeeUtils> mockedScope = Mockito.mockStatic(EmployeeUtils.class)) {
    mockedScope.when(EmployeeUtils::fetchEmployees).thenReturn(emptyList());
    // rest of your test
}
```

Comment: It does not work for me. I am getting the same result as earlier. I put everything after mockedScope.when();

Answer (score 0):

You invoke static `EmployeeUtils.fetchEmployees` in `EmployeeBase` constructor.

If you want yo have `EmployeeUtils.fetchEmployees` stubbed when the constructor is being run, you need to run it in scope of `Mockito.mockStatic` block.

```
class EmployeeUtilsTest {

    @Test
    void saveEmployeeTest() {
        try (MockedStatic<EmployeeUtils> mockedScope = Mockito.mockStatic(EmployeeUtils.class)) {
            mockedScope.when(EmployeeUtils::fetchEmployees).thenReturn(Collections.emptyList());
            var response = Mockito.mock(Response.class);
            var employeeBase = new EmployeeBase(response);
        }
    }
}
```

In particular, if you initialize the employeeBase field in the @BeforeEach method, the constructor is not run in scope of mockedStatic block.

More generally, there are a few patterns in your code which make it harder to test:

- static utility classes
- calling external services from constructor of the object

Rethink the design before going fancy with mockStatic

Comment: I put everything inside try statement and I am still getting the same error as before. I removed everything above like InjectMocks, Mocks, BeforeEach method.